# Nested styles don't work in my component' styles

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In my `Nuxt` application I have nested styles in the standard `LESS/SCSS` syntax. Very simple stuff yet the browser doesn't understand it:

```
<style scoped>
.telephone {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;

  .icon-telephone {
    margin-right: 1em;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    width: 20px;
  }
}
</style>
```

In Chrome's console I literally see this:

```
.telephone {
    .icon-telephone {: ;
    margin-right: 1em;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    width: 20px;
    }: ;
}
```

.. with everything from `.icon-telephone {: ;` to `}: ;` struck through.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you should check this:

https://nuxtjs.org/faq/pre-processors/

Install pre-pocessors and use the `lang` attribute.

```
<style lang="scss">
.red {
  color: red
}
</style>
```